# Value being overwritten on every call of the class

Tags: c#

I am using filehelpers and I am generating a guid on the start of the read in from the class however the guid is being changed on every call that is not what I want I want when it first assigns the data to the file helper class it holds the guid for that row.

The class I am using

```
[DelimitedRecord(",")]
[IgnoreEmptyLines]
public class FuelPumpData
{
    [FieldHidden]
    private string  _guid;

    [FieldHidden]
    public  String Code
    {
        get
        {
            return _guid ?? (_guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")); 
        }
    }
    [FieldQuoted]
    public string Date { get; set; }
    [FieldQuoted]
    public string Time { get; set; }
    [FieldQuoted]
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    [FieldQuoted]
    public string CustomerName2 { get; set; }
    public string SystemGroup1 { get; set; }
    [FieldQuoted]
    public string CardCode { get; set; }
    [FieldQuoted]
    public string SystemGroup4 { get; set; }
    public decimal FuelQty { get; set; }
    public decimal FuelValue { get; set; }
    [FieldQuoted]
    public string FuelType { get; set; }
    [FieldQuoted]
    public string SiteName { get; set; }
    [FieldQuoted]
    public string Pump { get; set; }
}
```

As you can see I am generating the guid ok but without the dashes but I dont believe correctly as its being over written every time.

As I am of course using file helpers I will show my method here.

```
 var engine = new FileHelperEngine<FuelPumpData>();
 var productSales = engine.ReadFile(Filename);
```

When I go to query my table for the guid that is in the code its not there at all and that is because I beleive I am creating a new guid every time in my class when i want it to retain its value for that row.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking here, every time you construct a new object of `FuelPumpData`, it's going to start with the `_guid` field as `null`. The first time you read the `Code` property, a value will be assigned to `_guid`, then returned, and any subsequent times you read the `Code` property, you will get the value that was initially assigned. However, you don't seem to have any way of *setting* that value, so I'm not sure what purpose it serves.

Comment: Are you simply missing a setter for the `Code` property?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you put a setter like this

```
public String Code
        {
            get
            {
                return _guid ?? (_guid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"));
            }
            set
            {
                _guid = value;
            }
        }
```